# Boot process hangs on "A start job is running for Hold until boot process finished"

Tags: boot, 17.10

I am struggling to boot the OS after shutting down last night, It is a single boot Ubuntu on a 2011 MacBook Pro, device all working last night and now all I get is this for like 20 minutes before I give up.

I tried both <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Escape</kbd> to boot into recovery and neither seemed to work.

It mentions

```
[FAILED] Failed to start LSB: Xen daemons
```

then hangs on `a start job is running for...`

Any advice?

[image: boot screenshot]

Comment: Please add your entire boot log.

Comment: I tried, It would not allow me to post a photo

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/J5R9b

Comment: theoretically you press left shift or escape immediately after turning on the machine to bring up the GRUB menu. If you can't do it, you can boot from USB and `chroot` into your system to run commands. Please comment if you still need help with this

Comment: Will give this a try and see how I go, Worst case I will bike the system as there is nothin on it right now but I would really like to solve it in case it happens in future